# buildr use optional transitive artifact dependency

Tags: dependencies, buildr

How can Apache Buildr be told to follow dependencies with `<optional>true</optional>` in the pom? See the related question at [Trouble getting Hibernate Core and Hibernate Annotations using Apache Ivy (but it's also Maven2 related.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520902/trouble-getting-hibernate-core-and-hibernate-annotations-using-apache-ivy-but-it)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm afraid that transitive support is experimental in buildr, there are a few problems with it. Tou could try listing the dependencies by hand:

```
HIBERNATE = ["mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.13",
         "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.5.5-Final",
         "antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6",
         "commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1",
         "commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4",
         "commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.3",
         "commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5",
         "dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1",
         "xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2",
         "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.5.5-Final",
         "org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.5.5-Final",
         "org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final",
         "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final",
         "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.1.0.Final",
         "javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA",
         "cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2",
         "javassist:javassist:jar:3.9.0.GA",
         "javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1",
         "log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16",
         "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1",
         "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1",
         "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1"]
```

Comment: That's a possibility. For now I hand-editet the hibernate-core pom in .m2, removing the _JDK4 suffix from the jboss-jee dependency (not directly related to this question), and also forcing the optional code generation by adding javassist manually.